# How can prove this $\binom{n}{p}\equiv \left\lfloor\frac{n}{p}\right\rfloor \pmod {p^2}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences

Show that if $n \gt p \gt 0$:
$$\binom{n}{p}\equiv \left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{p} \right\rfloor\pmod{ p^2}$$
where $p$ is prime.
and
$$\binom{n}{p}=\dfrac{n!}{(n-p)!p!}$$
This is theorem? True or false? If wrong, can you find $p$ prime and $n$ such that
$$\binom{n}{p}\equiv \ ? \mod {p^2}$$ Thank you everyone

Comment: Just edited your question. Did I get it right?

Comment: $\binom{3}{2} = 3 \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, while $[3/2] = [1.5] = 1$.

Comment: yes,Thank you @AndreasCaranti

Comment: Thank you @AndreasCaranti, so $$\binom{n}{p}\equiv ?(mod p^2)$$

Comment: @edoarad This one is $\text{mod } p^2$

Comment: The general answer should follow from http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/BinCoeff.pdf but I'm sure there's a simpler, more direct answer in this particular case.

Comment: What is $\left[\frac{n}p\right]$ here?

Comment: @Zander, here $[x]$ is used for the floor function $\lfloor x \rfloor = \max \{ z \in \Bbb{Z} : z \le x \}$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti then the equivalence in the question title rarely holds, counterexamples abound.

Comment: @Zander, I agree, see my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

As I said in a comment, a very general answer is provided by [this article by Andrew Granville](http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/BinCoeff.pdf).

In this particular case it appears we have 
$$
\binom{n}{p} \equiv \binom{n_{0}}{p} + p \binom{n_{1}}{p}\pmod{p^{2}}
$$
where
$$
n = n_{0} + n_{1} p^{2} + \dots. 
$$
is the decomposition of $n$ in base $p^{2}$.

This can be seen, as in [Lucas' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_theorem) by first analyzing $$(1 + x)^{p^{2}} \pmod {p^{2}},$$ and then $$(1 + x)^{n} = (1+x)^{n_{0}} (1+x)^{p^{2} n_{1}} \cdots \pmod{p^{2}}.$$