# How to prove ${n \choose p} \equiv\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p} \right\rfloor\pmod p$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

> Prove ${n \choose p} \equiv \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p} \right\rfloor \pmod p$

($n$ is natural and $p$ is a prime number)

How can i prove this statement?

Comment: You use Lucas's theorem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can prove this $\binom{n}{p}\equiv \left\lfloor\frac{n}{p}\right\rfloor \pmod {p^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437371/how-can-prove-this-binomnp-equiv-left-lfloor-fracnp-right-rfloor-pmo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lucas' theorem states that if we have two naturals $n,m$ and prime $p$, we can write $n$ and $m$ in base $p$:

$$n=n_0+n_1p+\cdots+n_kp^k ,\qquad m=m_0+m_1p+\cdots+m_kp^k$$

where $0\le n_i, m_i \le p-1$. Then:

$$\binom{n}{m}\equiv\prod_{i=0}^{k}\binom{n_i}{m_i}\bmod p$$

And so if $m=p$, we know that $p = 0 + 1 \cdot p$ in base $p$, so we get:

$$\binom{n}{p}\equiv\binom{n_0}{0} \binom{n_1}{1} \binom{n_2}{0} \binom{n_3}{0} \cdots\bmod p$$

Or:

$$\binom{n}{p}\equiv n_1 \bmod p$$

How do we get the digit $n_1$? It's like asking how to get the tens place digit in base $10$ from a number $1234$. You floor-divide it by the base (turn $1234$ into $123$) and then take that number mod the base ($123$ mod $10$ is $3$, which is the digit we were after).

Similarly, $n_1 = \lfloor\frac{n}{p}\rfloor \bmod p$, which means:

$$\binom{n}{p} \equiv \left\lfloor\frac{n}{p} \right\rfloor \bmod p$$

Answer (score 3):

$\binom{n}{p} = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-(p-1))}{p(p-1)!} \mod p$

There are exactly $p$ terms in the numerator. Let $n-r$ be divisible by $p$ where $0 \le r \le p-1$

$\binom{n}{p} = \frac{(n-r)}{p} \frac{(p-1)!}{(p-1)!}\mod p = \frac{n-r}{p} =\lfloor\frac{n}{p}\rfloor$